# How to call a C# function from my razor page in the script?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KdPj4.png)
Every time i run this it goes to the c function before I even press the button.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. please include code, error messages, and other _text-based_ information ***as text***, not as screenshot. i recommend [taking the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), as well as reading [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what's on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). also, keep in mind: the complete razor view, with all c#-code, gets executed _before it is sent to the browser_. and therefore before any client-side JS _can be executed_.

Comment: You need to revisit the basics of a web application stack. You have a division of server side application and the web client application. These are 2 different nodes. You can't call your c# code directly from client side code as they are executing on 2 different nodes. If you want your client side code to communicate to the server you have to make a web call back to the server (this is very common). You can research how to do this with ajax from javascript. You will also need to write server side code to process such a request, see web-api for c#.

Comment: In order for anyone to offer some help you need to show us your code for the page and explain in some detail what you wish to do.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to call C#function in script,you can try to use ajax to call controller action,and call the c# function in the action,here is a demo:

```
public IActionResult TestFunction() {
            return View();
        }
        public List<string> CallFunction()
        {
            return function();
        }
        public List<string> function()
        {
            return new List<string> { "1", "2", "3" };
        }
```

View:

```
<input id="data" />
<button onclick="CallFunction()">CallFunction</button>
<script>
    function CallFunction() {
        $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: 'CallFunction',
        }).done(function (result) {
            $("#data").val(result.toString());
            });
    }
</script>
```

result:
[image]

Comment: out of interest, what do you use to capture your gif?

Comment: I get 404 error when I do this. I think its something todo with the url.

Comment: Can  you share your url,your url may be wrong.